# Unable to install java9 on ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation, dependencies

I already have java8 working but when I try to install java9 this is what happens everytime:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done Package oracle-java9-installer is not
>   available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that
>   the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from
>   another source
>
> E: Package 'oracle-java9-installer' has no installation candidate

Comment: Have you tried downloading the tarball from Oracle's website?

Comment: No , I have not tried that but why am I facing this issue???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

do

```
sudo apt install default-jre default-jdk
```

Comment: Well thanks, it has installed the newer version of java, but still I face the same issue while using  "sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer"

Comment: im sorry to hear that, but java 9 is depreciated by alot of projects

Answer (score 4):

It seems Oracle stopped supporting Java 9 so the PPA does not contain Java9 installer anymore. There is nothing wrong on your end, with your machine.

It looks like Java9 is a short-term support version, and so will java 10 be too. Java 11 will be a LTS support. For more details on the new Java release approach see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50333498/10226875).

Because this, you can't install Java9 using the ppm anymore, you have to do it manually. You will have to go to the [java 9 archive downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase9-3934878.html), log in with an Oracle account, download the .tar.gz, extract the .tar.gz and copy it to the install location.