# How to Open Eclipse from the Terminal

Tags: eclipse, shell, terminal

launching vscode in terminal is "code . "

launching IntelliJ in terminal is "idea . "

launching Elcipse in terminal is "?"

I am new to Eclipse, does this mean I downloaded the IDE wrong?
Does Eclipse not have terminal/command line support?

Comment: There should be an "eclipse" binary in what you downloaded--usually all lowercase.

Comment: what is your os? where did you download the eclipse?

Comment: from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ @JRichardsz && MAC

Comment: on macOS Eclipse installs as a proper Mac application, like all apps you use the `open` command - `open -a Eclipse`

Comment: The binary may not be added to PATH. Have you checked if it is at e.g. `/opt/eclipse/eclipse-4.2/eclipse`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, download it from the official site:

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

If you love the shell, download the tar.gz not the installer:

**eclipse-java-2022-09-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz**

[image]

Uncompress it and you will see the executable file

[image]

Then open a shell with java available and run

```
./eclipse
```

Eclipse will be opened

[image]

Same steps should be work on mac and windows.

### java

Latest version had java included, but If you had an error related to missing java, you don't need to install it. Just [download](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62157040/3957754) it and export these variables in the shell

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/foo/Apps/openjdk-aaa-bbb
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Java is included, does not need to be installed.